# Granting privileges to root won't let me login?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I was trying to access my root user remotely from any IP, so I found this snippet. Yes, I know it's a security issue but there's literally no sensitive information on the database.

Anyways, When I executed this statement it now says:

> Connection for control user as defined in your configuration failed.

This is a very wide open ended issue that can have a lot of causes but it happened when I executed this query and now I can't login to root.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by 'mypassword';
```

So I'm in a bit of a situation since I can no longer access my database.

Comment: have you run "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" after run the code abover  on the server?

Comment: I can't log back in to flush them. It logged the root account out instantly.

Comment: restart the server then.

Comment: Restarted, I commented out the bind address so I could login with pma to flush the priveleges (Not that it even matters huh?) and I still can't access the database with any account other than pma locally.

Comment: ok, what is happening is: You have multiple root users. MySQL uses the pair user/host to try to find a match for your user, and it is always gonna be the most specific one. This means that if you have privileges for root@127.0.0.1 and also root@% MySQL is gonna try to use the first one. Remove it or even use an other username, instead root and then it should work fine.

Comment: I tried that and now it's not letting me get in at all anymore. :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to get a bit clever.

If you can download a zip of the version of mysql you have installed and unzip it somewhere not in you actual installed mysql location. You can then rename the existing `/data/mysql` folder and copy the vanilla `/data/mysql` directory over your now messed up one. This should reset you to its initial state.

You will of course have to re-create all the other mysql accounts ( if you created any ).

And this time I would create a new account for your remote access, and if necessary give that all privilages.